# DRF forms - 'str' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use the example found here - `http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/`

I'm literally cut/pasting from the example changing it to my own model -

I'm accessing the form through the following code in my base.html -

```
{% include 'dashboard/widget_detail.html' %}
```

widget_details.html

```
{% load rest_framework %}

<h1>Profile - {{ widget.name }}</h1>

<form action="{% url 'widget-detail' pk=widget.pk '%}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

views.py

```
class WidgetDetail(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'dashboard/widget_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, pk):
        widget= get_object_or_404(Widget, pk=pk)
        serializer = WidgetSerializer(widget)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'widget': widget})

    def post(self, request, pk):
        widget= get_object_or_404(Widget, pk=pk)
        serializer = WidgetSerializer(widget)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'widget': widget})
        return redirect('widget-list')
```

When trying to load the URL for my base.html I get the following traceback -

```
Traceback:
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/enterpass/gui/views.py" in display_base
  37.                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  45.             using=using)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  115.                         template_name, context, context_instance, dirs, dictionary)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in render_to_string
  221.             return t.render(context_instance)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  159.                 return template.render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  211.                 return self._render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  507.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  493.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  578.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  495.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'widget-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: [u'api/widgets/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', u'api/widgets/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$']
```

I have no idea what I'm missing/doing wrong.

I can access `http://localhost/api/widgets/5` no problem (as an example)

Update - if I remove the PK value from the form -

```
<form action="{% url 'api:widget-detail' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

I get the following error -

```
'str' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Which makes sense because I have no data yet.  All I want is a blank form using my serializer as a backend to fill out and "save".  How hard is this to do?!

Including my urls.py where it's resolving from -

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'widgets', views.WidgetViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: That first error is telling you you have no matching URL pattern for the URL you are trying to reach. What URL is your form at and what does your urls.py look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message gives you a clue; it says that it is using an empty string as the `pk` parameter. This means that for some reason `widget.pk` is evaluating to empty.

Comment: Hey ya there's no PK because I want a blank form that I can then put my own data in and post.  I found this stackoverflow `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047855/django-rest-framework-form` and it looks like what I'm asking isn't possible?  if I go to `http://localhost/api/widgets/` it gives me a list and a blank form at the bottom I can fill to post.  All I want is to be able to use that blank form inside another template somewhere.

Comment: It's perfectly possible of course, but then you shouldn't try to submit to a detail view that requires a PK. You need another pattern in your urls.py that accepts the POST at /api/widgets, without the /5.

Comment: so the problem is that it's resolving my post to `[u'api/widgets/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', u'api/widgets/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$']` instead of just `api/widgets`?

Comment: Yes, because that's what you've told it to do. You need a different pattern, without the `?P<pk>...`.